# Duplicate along curve without transformation in Blender 2.80

Tags: modeling

I looked at the lessons for version 2.7. In version 2.8 I cannot find the Dupliсate tab in the object properties and the Frames button in it. Does anyone know how to duplicate along curve in Blender 2.8?